# How to deal with white space in column names to use spark coalesce function in expr method

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on spark `coalesce` functionality in my project.Code works fine on columns with no spaces but fails on spaced columns.

**e1.csv**

```
id,code,type,no root
1,,A,1
2,,,0
3,123,I,1
```

**e2.csv**

```
id,code,type,no root
1,456,A,1
2,789,A1,0
3,,C,0
```

**logic code**

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/user/Videos/<folder>/e1.csv");

        Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("/home/user/Videos/<folder>/e2.csv");


Dataset<Row> newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id== b.id").selectExpr("coalesce(`a.no root`,`b.no root`) AS `a.no root`");

newDS.show();
```

### What I have tried

```
Dataset<Row> newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id== b.id").selectExpr("""coalesce(`a.no root`,`b.no root`) AS `a.no root`""");
```

The espexted result would be like

```
no root
1
0
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following criteria

```
val newDS = df1.as("a").join(df2.as("b")).where("a.id==b.id").selectExpr("coalesce(a.`no root`,b.`no root`) AS `a.no root`")
```

will generate the expected output

```
+---------+
|a.no root|
+---------+
|        1|
|        0|
|        1|
+---------+
```